# Does a symlink from a wxallowed mounted partition apply wxallowed when the target is a partition without wxallowed?

Tags: mount, symlink, openbsd

If I configured the following symlink:

```
/usr/local/symlink@ -> /var/target/
```

Using default disklabel partitions, is the [`wxallowed`](https://man.openbsd.org/mount#wxallowed) mount option applied to the target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested with `wxallowed`, but I expect it to be the same as links to files in file systems mounted `read only`, which can't be written to. The symlink is a link to a name, not to the object itself, so when you open the symlink you are opening the target file, thus with the permissions given by the target file system's flags.

Comment: I think what you are saying is: the file opened from `/usr/local/symlink@` will be opened with the permissions of `/var/target`?

Comment: Yes. You don't "open" the symlink, you open its _target_.